# What APL expression best emulates the SQL select statement, given a matrix

Tags: select, filter, boolean, apl, dyalog

I have CSV files with numeric data and I would like to perform analysis on this data. I am hoping that using APL will give me more flexibility than reading this into mysql and performing selects. But to start with I would like to do simple extractions like 'select * from mydata where col1 = 2020'. So far I understand I can use Compress. But for that I need to know the expression that would yield the boolean array for the left argument of compress (i.e. the APL version of 'where col1 = 2020'). Online searches did not get me anywhere in that department.

Comment: You can get higher quality answers if you specify which implementation and version of APL you use.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that and thanks for the quick response. I'm using Dyalog 18.

Comment: I've added a section about utilising Dyalog APL features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed right in your speculations.

"col1 = 2020" would be `mydata[;1] = 2020` so the entire thing is `(mydata[;1] = 2020) ⌿ mydata`

My father liked to define

```
∇ data ← data where condition
  data ← condition⌿data
∇
```

so he could write things like `data where data[;1] = 2020`

#### Utilising Dyalog APL features

Dyalog APL provides some notational niceties:

- The inline expression can be written as `mydata ⌿⍨ mydata[;1] = 2020`
- The above definition of `where` can be written simply as `where ← ⌿⍨`

Comment: I see. Nice! Curious: is there a way to avoid repeating the mydata reference?

Comment: @RudiAngela There are many variations possible, especially if you begin defining operators. E.g. `select ← {⍵ ⌿⍨ ⍺⍺ ⍵} ⋄ col ← ⌷⍤1⍨` allows you to write `(2020=col∘1)select mydata` or you could define `col ← {⍵ ⌿⍨ ⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵[;⍵⍵]} ⋄ in←⊢` and write `2020 = col 1 in mydata`

Comment: @RudiAngela Feel free to visit https://apl.chat to discuss further.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tip.